# Is there a size limit for data returned by Net::SSH.exec command

Tags: ruby, ssh, ls, net-ssh

I am trying to do file listing of a remote machine using the below code.

```
Net::SSH.start(host_name, 'ec2-user') do |ssh|
  cmd = "ls #{get_ls_command(dir_loc, extension)}"
  ssh.exec!(cmd) do |channel, stream, data|
  if stream == :stderr
    # do something -- and error has been raised. 
    # for now raise an exception 
    puts data
    raise "Error in fetching file data"
 end
 return data.split("\n")
end
```

If the number of files is large then the data that is getting returned from exec command is truncated and only a partial listing of file is returned. Seems to me that there is a size limit. Anyone knows how I can increase it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't complete, you are missing an `end` and have a "wrong" indentation which doesn't represent the actual nesting. However, I'll try to work with what we have

The method yields the received data in chunks to the block. In your return statement, `data` is actually pointing to the last returned chunk of said data. That means your code only works by accident if the block is only yielded once (which it does with at most 8000 byte iirc).

To be safe with multiple yields, you have to first gather the data completely and then properly handle it. You can do it with something like this:

```
Net::SSH.start(host_name, 'ec2-user') do |ssh|
  cmd = "ls #{get_ls_command(dir_loc, extension)}"

  result = ""
  ssh.exec!(cmd) do |channel, stream, data|
    if stream == :stderr
      # do something -- and error has been raised. 
      # for now raise an exception 
      puts data
      raise "Error in fetching file data"
    end
    result << data
  end

 return result.split("\n")
end
```

Comment: Sorry about the bad indentation and missing end. I don't think the block is being yielded more than once. Atleast the experimentation I did seem to suggest that is being yielded exactly once. Is there something else I need to do?